# angular input type number, negative value android number pad

Tags: android, angularjs, html, input, angular-ngmodel

I have created a website and have the following line

```
 <input type="number" ng-model="myNumber" min="-40" max="50">
```

now when I want to enter a value on my android mobile phone, it opens the android number picker virtual keyboard and there is no minus sign so I can't insert values below 0.

Is there a way to use input type **number**? Or do I have to use

```
<input type="text">
```

which makes things more complicated to validate?

Thanks